# При нажатии комбинации клавиш раздаётся звук и ввода нет

Tags: windows-7

Например, **не работают** сочетания
<kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>
<kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>
<kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>

Но при этом **работают**
<kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>
<kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>

Система начинает издавать сигналы, как при залипании клавиш.

Если открою стандартный windows блокнот, и зажму <kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>, то в блокнот будет записываться 6666666666666666666...

Если зажму <kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>, то ничего записываться не будет, будет сигнал звуковой через каждые 0.8 секунды. Залипание клавиш отключено.

Как узнать из-за чего подобное?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это называется Key jamming and ghosting. Сама по себе технология изготовления дешевых клавиатур - две пленки с пересекающимися дорожками - накладывает ограничение на количество одновременных нажатий. Но при этом экономит материалы - не надо вести два провода к каждой кнопке! Т.е. из матрицы n + m проводов получается сделать аж n * m кнопок. Но это вызывает проблему определения одновременных нажатий:

Например, кнопки <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> могут быть реализованы двумя парами дорожек: A1, A2, B1, B2:

- <kbd>A</kbd> замыкает A1, B1
- <kbd>B</kbd> замыкает A1, B2
- <kbd>C</kbd> замыкает A2, B1
- <kbd>D</kbd> замыкает A2, B2

и вот при нажатии одновременно на <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> получаются замкнуты еще и A2, B2, хотя <kbd>D</kbd> не нажата. Это эффект Keyboard Ghosting. <kbd>D</kbd> - кнопка-призрак.

Это не так страшно при наборе текста - но вот в играх это вызывает неприятный эффект. Пытался подпрыгнуть и повернуть одновременно - и бросил себе под ноги гранату.

Производители клавиатур решают эту следующими хаками:

- делают разводку, которая учитывает стандартные раскладки в играх (<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>)
- для того же <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> впаивают isolation diodes (что удорожает клавиатуру)
- для всех остальных проблемных комбинаций - тупо игнорируют их и выдают ошибку

Последнее называется Keyboard Jamming, и вот именно его вы и наблюдаете. Для дешевых клавиатур это срабатывает примерно на 5% трехбуквенных комбинаций.

[Объяснение проблемы и тулза для теста на сайте MS Applied Sciences](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx)

[Статья в вики на эту тему](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29)

Comment: А как узнать что клава поддерживает нажатие множества кнопок? Где нибудь есть инфа о том, на какой клавиатуре можно нажимать сколько кнопок одновременно?

Comment: @manking обычно это считается фичей и явно упоминается как N-Key Rollover - KNRO. У меня, например, Das Keyboard - механика, а не пленки, так что воспроизвести проблему из вопроса было немного затруднительно )

Answer (score 0):

Варианты:

1) Нестандартный драйвер (многие производители предоставляют свое ПО для тонкой настройки) на клавиатуру.

2) Слиплись (перемыкают) дорожки на самой клавиатуре.